# How to insert data in nested div

Tags: insert, nested

I want to insert data in paragraph which is in nested div. plz guide me how to insert data in this paragraph through selenium web driver. Code is given below.

```
<div class="modal-body"> 
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-xs-12 m-t-md"> 
            <div class="note-editing-area"> 
                <div class="note-editor note-frame panel panel-default"> 
                    <p> I want to insert text in this paragraph </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

Comment: Mate, you haven't posted the code, edit and post the code.
Also, try something yourselves and then we can help you with where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: here is the code:<div class="modal-body">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 m-t-md">
<div class="note-editing-area">
<div class="note-editor note-frame panel panel-default">
<p>
I want to insert text in this paragraph
</p>

Comment: If you have found the answer to your own question, please post an answer to your own question and close it.

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution for access an element which exist in multiple div we can identified it with class `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,' ')]")) you can use ur element class name in ' class name' –`